# Получить конец недели исходя из переданной даты

Tags: python

Есть ли какой-то простой способ получить конец недели исходя из произвольной даты? Например если передать в функцию 14.04.2023 то она вернет 16.04.2023 23:59:59. Я смотрел документацию модуля time и datetime, но не смог разобраться

Comment: вряд ли есть готовая функция, но вы можете написать свою, это не так и сложно

Comment: я бы с радостью, не смог разобраться как. Не пойму только как рассчитать сколько нужно добавить к дате time.time() чтобы получился конец недели

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм, можно попытаться сделать так:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

input_date = datetime(2023, 4, 14)

def next_week(date):
    days_to_next_week = 7 - date.isoweekday()
    result = (timedelta(days=days_to_next_week) + date).strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
    return result

output_date = next_week(input_date)

print(output_date)
```

`date.isoweekday()` - возвращает текущий день недели в виде числа. 1 = Понедельник, 2 = Вторник ... 7 = Воскресенье.

`timedelta(days=days_to_next_week) + date` - сколько осталось дней + введённая дата.

`strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')` - далее переводим в формат который вы хотели.

| Символ | Значение |
| --- | --- |
| %d | Текущий день в формате DD |
| %m | Текущий месяц в формате MM |
| %Y | Текущий год в формате YYYY |
| %H | Текущий час |
| %M | Текущая минута |
| %S | Текущая секунда |

---

А чтобы добиться конкретно конца дня, можно сделать так:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

input_date = datetime(2023, 4, 14)

def next_week(date):
    days_to_next_week = 7 - date.isoweekday()
    result = (timedelta(days=days_to_next_week + 1) + date - timedelta(seconds=1)).strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
    return result

output_date = next_week(input_date)

print(output_date)
```

`timedelta(days=days_to_next_week + 1) + date - timedelta(seconds=1)` - эквивалентно = `недостоющее_кол-во_дней_до_конца_недели + 1_день + текущая_дата - 1_секунда`

Comment: только надо принудительно на 23:59:59 выставить

Comment: @Эникейщик уже заметил :) Дополнено.

Comment: @ΝNL993 огромное спасибо!

Comment: @alexeyromashev не за что! Не забудьте ознакомиться со ссылкой которую предоставил Эникейщик.

Answer (score 3):

Весь код писать не буду, потому что не знаю, в каком виде приходят данные и в каком должны быть на выходе.

Есть функция `date.isoweekday()` ([ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday)), возвращает порядковый номер дня недели указанной даты (дата - объект `datetime`). Можно этот номер отнять от 7, получить количество дней до воскресенья, полученное число прибавить любым удобным способом к значению `day` объекта `datetime`, получится дата воскресенья. А время всегда одинаковое 23:59:59.

Comment: спасибо, теперь понятна логика!